# Is it possible to force linker errors in gcc/g++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Consider the next C/C++ code:

```
//Main.c 

#include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl_cblas.h"

int tfuuuuuuuuuuuuuu()
{
   int Num = 10;
   double A[30] = {0.0};
   double B[30] = {0.0};
   double C[9];
   cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasTrans, CblasNoTrans, 3, 3, Num, 1.0, A, 3, B, 3, 0.0, C, 3);
   return 0;  

}
```

Building this in MSVC 2015 (x64 Win7) in a DLL project gives linker error:

`unresolved external symbol cblas_dgemm referenced in function tfuuuuuuuuuuuu`

As it should because I did not link against the blas library.

But building the same code in gcc (8.2.0, Centos7)

`$ gcc -c -fPIC -I./include -o Main.o Main.c`

`$ gcc -shared -o libTest.so Main.o`

didn't give any linking errors!.

1. Why am I not getting the linker error even though I didn't link against the  needed library?
2. Is there a linker option to force linker error in this case?

Comment: You may be looking for `-Wl,-z,defs` I believe.

Comment: Here's a nice little list of useful flags: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/03/21/compiler-and-linker-flags-gcc/